# Display a column showing the tags set by Dolphin

Tags: dolphin, tag

In Dolphin 2 you can add tags to files, but you can't add a column in the detailed view to display them.
Is there a way to select files based on their tags ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Dolphin 2.1 and I can show tags in the detailed view. Just right click on the column header and select tag.

[image: click on the column header]

Comment: When I asked the question, the version was 2.0, and this feature was missing. Apparently it's time to upgrade.

Comment: I suspected that might have been the case. I'm glad to be able to motivate you into the present. :)

Answer (score -2):

Yes. It is possible but you have to read the tutorial

---

See this from the manual [Columns](http://userbase.kde.org/Dolphin/File_Management#Columns)

---

as well as this [Folders](http://userbase.kde.org/Dolphin/File_Management#Folders)

---

The complete manual is [HERE](http://userbase.kde.org/Dolphin) along with tutorials

---

Since KDE 4.1 it is possible to display the folders as a tree. In this mode a plus sign is shown next to the folder. By clicking on this sign the folder is expanded and all containing sub folders and files are also shown in the table but they are attenuated. By clicking the sign, which display a minus now, again the expansion is closed again. Of course the tree structure can be used for as many folders as wished. The tree view is disabled by default, but can be activated via Settings -> Configure Dolphin -> View Modes -> Details with option Expandable Folders.

Comment: I don't see how your answer relates to displaying the tags in Dolphin.